# Python equivalent to echo -e?

Tags: python

Is there a python equivalent to `echo -e`?

In other words, is there a built-in function to convert `r"\x50\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e"` to `"Python"` in Python?

*Edit*
I added the 'r' prefix, to make sure everyone understands that I do not want the python interpreter to convert this. Rather, I want to convert that 24-character string to a 6-character one.

Comment: Where is this input coming from and how are you viewing it?

Comment: This is actually coming from the output of `strace -xx`.

Comment: I tried to make the edit by adding the r but you beat me my a couple seconds. :)

Comment: @Ray, I encourage you not to make semantic edits like that on issues along these lines, where many posters may be making a different mistake than the one Jonathon was.

Comment: Also +1 for a question that got me looking at the codecs.

Comment: @Mike I ordinarily would not have but attempted only after seeing his answer below in which he _used_ the r.  But yes thanks for the warning; it is absolutely true that one cannot infer the intent of the OP.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct way to do this, which I just found is

```
>>> a = r"\x50\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e"
>>> print a
\x50\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e
>>> a.decode('string_escape')
'Python'
```

Make sure you are escaping the backslashes (or using the raw 'r' prefix) when testing this!

References:

- http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode
- http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `r` notation, I didn't remember that :) Remember that it's OK (and even encouraged) to accept your own answer if you decide that it's the best one.

Answer (score 3):

No conversion is necessary. They are already the same string

```
>>> "\x50\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e" == "Python"
True
```

If you *actually* have a different string `"\\x50\\x79\\x74\\x68\\x6f\\x6e"` which actually contains backslashes (`"\x50\x79\x74\x68\x6f\x6e"` does *not* contain any backslashes), then you would do

```
>>> s
'\\x50\\x79\\x74\\x68\\x6f\\x6e'
>>> s.decode('string-escape')
'Python'
```